# global variables in a shared library?

Tags: vala

I'm trying to add global variables to a shared library. Consider this example, in library libutils, globals.vala contains

```
namespace Libutils {
public static GLib.Object yorgi_obj;
public static int yorgi_int;
}
```

I see externs are properly generated in .c & .h files

```
libutils:globals.c
extern GObject* libutils_yorgi_obj;
GObject* libutils_yorgi_obj = NULL;
extern gint libutils_yorgi_int;
gint libutils_yorgi_int = 0;

libutils:globals.h
extern GObject* libutils_yorgi_obj;
extern gint libutils_yorgi_int;
```

My test program, tester.vala

```
int main(string[] args) {
    Libutils.yorgi_int = 1;
```

All is well in compiling tester.vala. But linking to Libutils.so I get

```
...tester.vala:614: undefined reference to `libutils_yorgi_int'
```

Do I have to specify some special vala attributes or pass something to the linker?

Comment: Unhelpful answer: Don't do that, use getters and setters or properties on a class. Otherwise, how are you compiling? (You ask if anything extra needs to be passed to the linker without telling us what your already passing)

Comment: Make sure the library is actually specified to the linker (like `-llibutils` or even better via pkg-config).

Comment: @JensMühlenhoff Your right! After posting I found my error in earlier makefile change to "libutils" instead of "libutils-dbg". Thanks!